# IText ignore UTF-8 characters when exporting java swing component

Tags: java, swing, itext

I am using this example to convert java swing JFrame to pdf: [export jcomponent to pdf with itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516633/export-jcomponent-to-pdf-with-itext). Problem is when my frame contains UTF-8 characters like čěř... .This characters are missing in exported document. How I can turn on this characters in my PDF ?

UPDATE:

I try your example but I got exception:

```
ExceptionConverter: com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: Font 'fonts/verdana.ttf,1' with 'Identity-H' is not recognized.
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:699)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:606)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.java:549)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.DefaultFontMapper.awtToPdf(DefaultFontMapper.java:107)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfGraphics2D.getCachedBaseFont(PdfGraphics2D.java:1082)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfGraphics2D.setFont(PdfGraphics2D.java:1075)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:855)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:874)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.printChildren(JComponent.java:1214)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1049)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1183)
 at GUI.PlayOffPanel.export(PlayOffPanel.java:322)
```

Look like there is some some problem with importing .ttf fonts like verdana or times but with example what you add it works. But I really want use Verdana font so still looking for answer

Comment: I don't have an answer but maybe some help on the way to resolve your issue. I used to have problem with JasperReport (which uses iText to generate PDF) and I had to add my font files (fonts that contains the needed characters) organized in a .jar (some XML and the TTF files)

Comment: I found TTF file of my font but what do you mean with xml ?

Comment: depends how did you encode non_ascii chars,

Comment: encode ? I have String name = "Aděm Čermák" which is added into JLabel  and in jframe it look good but in pdf file this characters are missing

Answer (score 3):

As you didn't show any code of your own, I take it that you used the code from [export jcomponent to PDF with itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516633/export-jcomponent-to-pdf-with-itext) (the question you referred to) as is. Thus, your code to retrieve a `Graphics2D` instance is:

```
Graphics2D g2d = tp.createGraphics(bill.getWidth(), bill.getHeight(), new DefaultFontMapper());
```

As documented in [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/), section 14.5.2 *Drawing text to PdfGraphics2D,* the `DefaultFontMapper` you use *assumes that each font uses the encoding Cp1252 (WinAnsi).* (Unfortunately this is **not** documented in the JavaDoc header for `DefaultFontMapper,` merely in the JavaDoc of its method `insertDirectory`.) This would explain your missing characters.

*You can fix this by adding a custom `BaseFontParameters` object to the mapper as was done* in the sample [Text1ToPdf2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=252) for `c:/windows/fonts/msgothic.ttc:`

```
// create a font mapper
DefaultFontMapper mapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
// map MS Gothic to the corresponding font program
BaseFontParameters parameters = new BaseFontParameters("c:/windows/fonts/msgothic.ttc,1");
parameters.encoding = BaseFont.IDENTITY_H;
mapper.putName("MS PGothic", parameters );
// Create a Graphics2D object
Graphics2D g2 = new PdfGraphics2D(canvas, 600, 60, mapper);
```

Depending on your use case it may be too tedious to do that for all fonts (probably) used, but there are alternatives explained in the very same section of the book: You can

- create a `FontMapper` implementation of your own (e.g. by subclassing the `DefaultFontMapper`),
- use the `AsianFontMapper` (in case of certain Asian character sets missing), or
- add the glyphs as shapes instead of characters stored in a font.

These options cover multiple pages in the book, too much to put into a single answer here. You can get a first impression by looking at the samples [Text2ToPdf1.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=254), [Text2ToPdf2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=255), and [Text2ToPdf3.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=256).